# RuntimeException Handling By Creating Custom Exception

Tags: java, exception, custom-error-handling

Custom RuntimeException class is not instance of Custom Exception class. But RuntimeException is instance of Exception. Why???

I created two exception classes for my project:

```
public class ABCRuntimeException extends RuntimeException {
    //Functions...
}

public class ABCException extends Exception {
    //Functions...
}
```

Now I am trying to handle those exception like this:

```
try{
    //Code which throw ABCRuntimeException
} catch(Exception e) {
    if(e instanceof ABCException) {
       System.out.println("Is instance of ABCException");
    } else if(e instanceof Exception) {
       System.out.println("Is instance of Exception");
    }
}
```

The output is `Is instance of Exception`. Why ABCRuntimeException is not instance of ABCException.

**And how to handle such exception scenario so that i can apply common logic for both ABCRuntimeException and ABCException without putting OR operator in if condition?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Why `ABCRuntimeException` is not instance of `ABCException`.

Because you didn't define it that way

```
public class ABCRuntimeException extends RuntimeException 

public class ABCException extends Exception
```

> And how to handle such exception scenario so that i can apply common
>   logic for both ABCRuntimeException and ABCException without putting OR
>   operator in if condition?

In this case, where your exceptions only share `Exception` as a supertype, `||` is appropriate. (You could also catch `Exception` if you didn't care about other types of exceptions thrown.)

Comment: Thanks @Sotirios Delimanolis. What changes are required to make ABCRuntimeException instanceif ABCException?

Comment: @AbhendraSingh You'd have to make `ABCRuntimeException` a subclass of `ABCException`, but then it wouldn't be a `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 0):

Extending exceptions of multiple classes is possible in java. If you extend it from ABCException and other parent exceptions this should work.